# Aggregate multiple perf profiles

Tags: linux, profiling, perf

I'm working on a managed runtime.  A code change went in which resulted in a regression in the rate at which the JIT compiler processes compilations. (That is, the act of compiling is slower, the resulting code being generated is unaffected.) This was observed using our standard benchmark.

I'm trying to nail down the mechanics underlying this regression.  I have been looking at pairs of profiles created from single runs of the benchmark.  For each pair, the first profile is generated with a build without the change, the second is generated with a build with is identical to the first, modulo the regression-causing change.

I'm finding that there aren't enough samples to make useful determinations when using a profile for a single run.  I would like to collect multiple profiles for both before and after (generally k for each of before and after), and merge them together to generate a smoother view of what's going on.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What is your host CPU (there can be IPT tracing in it or some hardware-based sampling)? Can you turn off all [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) features? Can you try to select higher perf sampling [frequency](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-record.1.html) (`-F 1000` and `-F 4000` options of `perf record`, check dmesg for warnings)? I suggest you to convert `perf.data` into EIP/RIP samples with `perf script` and then combine them with some script.